# Ctrl+c not working in integrated terminal which uses Powershell

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm using Powershell in the integrated terminal by adding the following line to the `settings.json` file.

`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",`

It works very well, but usually, when I'm in Powershell, typing `ctrl+c`  cancels what I had typed and opens a new line.

But in the integrated terminal it just prints `^C`.

Is there a way to fix it or find an alternative method to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: how did you add powershell to the integrated terminal, ctrl+c works for me

Comment: I updated my question explaining how I added Powershell to the integrated terminal.

Comment: try updating vscode? I have literally the same configuration and it works as expected, or what's the code you are trying to interrupt?

Comment: I'm using the latest version: `1.7.2` I'm not interested in interrupting code (at least not yet). What I really miss as that if I type anything, whatever, I expect that when I type Ctrl+c, it opens a new line underneath.

Comment: aaah, that it does not for me, right. I guess you shouled edit your question to reflect that, since it does interrupt, but doesnt' clear the line. `ctrl + x `clears the line

Comment: Question edited. Tried using `ctrl + x` but it doesn't clear the line.

Answer (score 0):

This is with VSCode and not necessarily with the PowerShell Extension. You can see this by just using the default cmd.exe terminal, CTRL+C does nothing. It does not print the `^C` at all, and creates no new line.

If you want this to work as expected in the normal command prompt or PowerShell.exe you will need to [submit an issue to VSCode repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) and request it.

I would expect this is all tied to the keybindings.json file. I went through that file but could not find a command available to the same function that occurs in the full command prompt or console. So this will likely need a new command added for VSCode.

If you search through the keybindings file you can see the terminal has that key CTRL+C bound to `copySelection` when `terminalFocus && terminalTextSelected`. This is why the `^C` is being output, and no new line is being added.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will erase the line back to the beginning.